# Javascript Object: a function or method in an attribute

Tags: javascript, object, methods, attributes

I am a trying to put the result of a method in an attribute, but I keep getting the error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'ppp'"**

This is my simple code:

```
var ttt = {
    ddd: 'I said '+ this.ppp() + '!!!',


    ppp:function(){
        return 'ok';
    }
};
alert(ttt.ddd)
```

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var ttt = {
    ddd:function(){
        return  'I said '+ this.ppp() + '!!!';
    },


    ppp:function(){
        return 'ok';
    }
};
alert(ttt.ddd())
```

This is OK . The code you write , ttt.ddd is a string , the 'this' is window object in browser.

Comment: Thx everyone, that is to say we cannot put the value returned by a method into an attribute within an object.
I'll move to the method solution

cheers

Comment: Only the function can create a new scope in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your code 'this' is referring to the window object.

To get around this, you could turn ttt into an auto-executing function

i.e

```
var ttt = function() {
function ppp(){
     return 'ok'   
}

return {
    ddd: 'I said '+ ppp() + '!!!',
    ppp: ppp
}
}();
```

At this point you can still use your original code to alert ddd

```
alert(ttt.ddd)
```

To see this in action go to http://jsfiddle.net/aCeqt/

Answer (score 1):

There is no block scope in javascript (only function scope), so **this.ppp()** refers to the global scope (which means it will be looking on the window object for **ppp**), as it is not inside a function.

You could rewrite it as follows:

```
var ttt = (function () {
    var innerttt = {
        ddd: function () {
            return 'I said ' + this.ppp() + '!!!';
        },
        ppp: function(){
            return 'ok';
        }
    };

    return innerttt;
})();

alert(ttt.ddd())
```

This will give **ddd** the scope it needs to call **ppp**.. which means the **this** part of **this.ppp()** will be looking inside the function for **ppp**

More info on scope and closures.. http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Comment: What's the point of wrapping this whole thing in a closure? It seems to work without the closure.

Comment: @Dogbert You are quite right, I have misread the question and over complicated the answer! allenm's answer is a better answer for this particular question

Comment: It's a nice looking solution, but it does change ddd from a property to a function, which doesn't need to happen.